# How to configure or style an Openlayers source?

Tags: views, javascript

I'm just getting started with Drupal Openlayers. I've created a simple map consisting of one views geojson view. What I want to know is how to customize the display of the layer, such as the type of marker for the points, etc. I'm just not sure where these setting are.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find any options in Views to customize the display.
Have a look under "admin/structure/openlayers".
Markers are defined under "styles" -> admin/structure/openlayers/styles.